# Android 3.2 remove title from action bar

Tags: android

I'm working with eclipse, android 3.2. and a virtual machine running android x86. (v3.2)

I use the Holo theme and I want to remove the action bar title and icon. So I do

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
}
```

It's working fine but ...

When the application start, I first show the title and icon and only after I see them disappearing.  So it's not very beautiful.

If I use debug, I can see It's only when I leave the onCreate that the setDisplayShowTitleEnabled takes effect.

So is there a way to hide title and icon before the activity is shown ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your Manifest

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityHere"
     android:label="">
```

Comment: Warning: you don't want to do this if it's your main activity. It will delete the label from your Launcher Icon. In that case, Kenneth's answer should work.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I discovered that later.

Answer (score 9):

I got around this by setting the "NoActionBar" holo theme in the android manifest and then setting the normal holo theme in onCreate().

Step 1: In styles.xml, added a custom theme resource.

```
<resources>
    <style name="ActionBar.CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar"/>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.CustomTheme</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Step 2: In my android manifest file I set the theme for the application and the "NoActionBar" holo theme for the startup activity.

```
<application
  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme
  ...

<activity
  android:name="MainActivity"
  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar">
  ...
```

Step 3: In the startup activity's onCreate()...

```
@Override
public void onCreate()(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.CustomTheme); // Set the custom theme which has the action bar.
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    ...
```