# How to hide app title in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

i have an action bar scherlock where i want to show logo without app title. I've just added in manifest **android:logo** tag and some code **getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false)** in my activity thats hide my title. It seems to work fine, but when app was started a title displays in a few seconds, how i can resolve this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326337/android-3-2-remove-title-from-action-bar and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7655874/how-do-you-remove-the-title-text-from-the-android-actionbar

Comment: @whizzzkey: you are mentioning about the black screen with title bar?

Comment: @Raghunandan it works, but if i set an activity label to "" an app name in android menu became "" too(remains only app icon)

Comment: @Aerrow no, i'm talking about "unhiddeble" title in my action bar, it hides but only few time ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just try this in order to hide title bar.

Use this in styles.xml file

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
```

Comment: but i dont need to hide whole bar, i want to hide a title only, and i've find a solution - is a display abs options in style like this  <item name="displayOptions">showHome|useLogo</item>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use custom title bar.
you can customize it as you like.
 [example](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/)

but use 45dip instead of 35dip