# Android - Hide titlebar in ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I tried to run action bar in android 2, so I used ActionBarSherlock, as you know when you are using ActionBarSherlock you should use some spesific themes, all of this themes have titlebar, how can I hide titlebar and use app in fullscrean mode? I tried `this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` but there is no achivment.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android 3.2 remove title from action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326337/android-3-2-remove-title-from-action-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
bar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);  
bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the actionbar go to the values/styles.xml and add this theme:

```
<style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Next go to your manifest and add this theme to your activity:

```
<activity 
android:name="yourActivityName"
android:theme="@style/NoActionBar">
</activity>
```

Comment: You can add the 2 item names in the theme you're currently using.